# Inject object with @ActivityScope in @ViewScope

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I'm using dagger 2.11 and it's not possible to inject Views [out of the box](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/720), but I managed to do so:

**BindingModule:**

```
@Module(subcomponents = {...})
public abstract class ViewBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewKey(MyView.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends BaseView> myView(MyViewSubComponent.Builder builder);
}
```

**MyViewSubComponent:**

```
@Subcomponent(modules = MyViewModule.class)
public interface MyViewSubComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyView> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyView> {}
}
```

**MyViewModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class MyViewModule extends ViewModule<MyView> {

    public MyViewModule(MyView view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
```

**ViewModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModule<V extends View> {

    protected final V view;

    public ViewModule(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    V provideView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

**BaseView:**

```
ViewInjection.inject(this);
```

**ViewInjection** is pretty much a copy from other Injectors.

Now, I've an Activity, a CustomView and a BaseViewModel. My BaseViewModel contains an Object which needs an instance of AppCompatActivity.

I'm provinding it as fallow:

**ActivityBindingModule**:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MyActivityModule.class)
    abstract MyActivity activity();
}
```

**MyActivityModule**

```
@Module
public abstract class MyActivityModule {

    @Binds
    abstract AppCompatActivity activity(MyActivity activity);
}
```

**The object who needs the context**:

```
 @Inject
 public Object(AppCompatActivity activity, ...)
```

**BaseViewModel**:

```
 public BaseViewModel(Object object,...)
```

**ViewModel (extends BaseViewModel)**:

```
 @Inject
 public ChildViewModel(Object object,...){super(object,...);...}
```

This configurations works pretty well when injecting my BaseViewModel inside the Activity (the "View"), but if I want to provide a BaseViewModel to a View (`@Inject BaseViewModel inside a BaseView`) I'll have a problem because my Object needs an Activity provided by the ActivityBindingModule/MyActivityModule which has `@ActivityScope` and not `@ViewScope`:

```
Error:(27, 1) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity is injected at
com.myapp.MyObject.<init>(activity, …)
com.myapp.MyObject is injected at
com.myapp.MyViewModel.<init>(object, …)
com.myapp.MyViewModel is injected at
com.myapp.MyViewModel.mMyViewModel
com.myapp.MyView is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
A binding with matching key exists in component: com.myapp.di...ActivityBindingModule_MyActivity.MyActivitySubcomponent
...
```

I don't know if I'm being clear here, a bit confusing perhaps, but how can I achieve this?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Didn't found a way to do this, changed the code to avoid this situation. Probably it's the best solution.