# ViewModel injection (inside View) with MVVM Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-databinding, android-mvvm

This is how I create an `Adapter` with **MVVM (+Databinding)** and **Dagger-2.11-rc2**:

**Adapter:**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BindableViewHolder<ViewDataBinding>>{
    private static int TYPE_A = 0;
    private static int TYPE_B = 1;

    ...

    @Override
    public BindableViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_A) {
            return new ItemViewHolder(new ItemRowView(parent.getContext()).getBinding());
        }
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BindableViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_A) {
            ((ItemViewHolderBinding) holder.getBinding()).getViewModel().setItemModel(((ItemModel) getItem(position)));
        }        
        ...
    }

    private static class ItemViewHolder extends BindableViewHolder<ItemViewHolderBinding> {
        ItemViewHolder(ItemViewHolderBinding binding) {
            super(binding);
        }
    }
}
```

**BindableViewHolder:**

```
public abstract class BindableViewHolder<ViewBinding extends ViewDataBinding> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ViewBinding mBinding;

    public BindableViewHolder(ViewBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        mBinding = binding;
    }

    public ViewBinding getBinding(){
        return mBinding;
    }
}
```

Since I'm using Dagger I wont be creating the `ViewModels` inside the `Adapter` instead they will be created (injected) inside their respective `Android.View`. And I guess it makes sense because my `Adapter` may have X `Android.View` types, those views can have Y `ViewModel`, etc...

**BaseView:**

```
public abstract class BaseView<ViewBinding extends ViewDataBinding, ViewModel extends BaseViewModel> extends FrameLayout {

    @Inject
    ViewModel mViewModel;
    protected ViewBinding mBinding;

    protected abstract void initBinding(final ViewBinding binding, final ViewModel viewModel);

    ...

    private void initView(Context context) {
        ViewInjection.inject(this);

        mBinding = DataBindingUtil...
        initBinding(mBinding, mViewModel);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**BaseViewModel**:

```
public class BaseViewModel extends BaseObservable {...}
```

**ItemRowView (or any View):**

```
public class ItemRowView extends BaseView<ItemRowViewBinding, ItemRowViewModel> {

    @Inject
    ViewModelA mViewModelA;
    @Inject
    ViewModelB mViewModelB;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void initBinding(ItemRowViewBinding binding, ItemRowViewModel viewModel) {
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setViewModelA(mViewModelA);
        binding.setViewModelB(mViewModelB);
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, this approach works fine with Activities, Fragments, etc, but when I use Views I have to create a **ViewInjecton** because Dagger doesn't have it out of the box. [This is how I do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400149/inject-object-with-activityscope-in-viewscope) (read until you've reached *"ViewInjection is pretty much a copy from other Injectors."*)

My question(s) is(are): Is this a good approach? I'm I using MVVM and Dagger correctly? Is there any better way to achieve this without creating **ViewInjecton** (and using Dagger-2.11)?

Thanks for your time.

ps: I've used the `Adapter` example but this approach is the same if I want to use Views instead of Fragments. With `Adapters` you are restricted to Views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has already been some discussion about whether one should inject inside Views or not in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075204/how-do-i-use-androidinjection-class-in-custom-views-or-other-android-classes).

> Since I'm using Dagger I wont be creating the ViewModels inside the Adapter instead they will be created (injected) inside their respective Android.View. And I guess it makes sense because my Adapter may have X Android.View types, those views can have Y ViewModel, etc...

I personally find this a little problematic and if I was working on a team with that code I would prefer a greater degree of separation between layers. At least,

1. There should be a clear model layer (that is retrieved from a repository or from the cloud for instance). These should be mere data objects.
2. The `Adapter` can deal with the model layer directly if it is easily related to the "item" layer i.e., the contents of the backing `List` for the `RecyclerView`.
3. The `ViewModel` for the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` should be extremely lightweight and not need injection. It should essentially be a bag of properties that easily translate into some property of the view (e.g., `setText()`, `setColor()`) and can be get/set. These can be created using the `new` keyword inside the `onBindViewHolder` method in the adapter. If this is difficult, you could extract a Factory (`ViewModelFactory`) and inject that as a dependency for your Adapter.

In short, the model data objects should be "dumb". The same goes for the `ViewModel` for the individual `ViewHolder`. The `Adapter` can be "intelligent" and can take tested "intelligent" dependencies (such as a `ViewModelFactory` if necessary) and this `Adapter` can be injected into your Activity or Fragment using Dagger 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite interesting your ViewModelFactory suggestion. So if you have an Activity's layout composed with 2 custom Views (could be included or not, I guess its the same) and each custom View has its own ViewModel. The Activity should "provide" (new.../Factory) those ViewModels to his custom Views? Bottom line, Activities/Fragments can have their ViewModels injected, but Android.Views should have them "provided"?

Comment: @GuilhE a View is a UI widget for rendering on the screen. It is nothing more. Activity and Fragment are more like co-ordinators and so it is permissible to inject dependencies for them. It's also possible to inject the Adapter for a RecyclerView and this would seem like a good place to inject a ViewModelFactory if you do need such a thing. In short, I would make the Views and their ViewModels as "stupid" as possible and add more "intelligence" at the level of the Adapter or the Activity/Fragment

Comment: Got it. I've marked your answer as "accepted" because I think this is the way to go too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518741/812269) that this should not be done, if you still want to do this, it is possible by going through the activity:

```kotlin
override val activity: FragmentActivity by lazy {
    try {
        context as FragmentActivity
    } catch (exception: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException("Please ensure that the provided Context is a valid FragmentActivity")
    }
}
override var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

This is discussed in more detail [here](https://sapandiwakar.in/accessing-viewmodel-inside-views-on-android-2/).